# estimation in case of censorship

Tags: estimation, censoring

Suppose we want to estimate the if people agree to suppose additional funds to a project. So, the answer is whether yes (1) or no (0). If the true proportion is $p$, our goal is to estimate the value of $p$. So, we ask random people if they agree to participate in this survey or not. They will accept with the probability of $q$, and reject with the probability of $1-q$ to participate. If we have asked $N$ people to answer in total, how is it possible to estimate the value of $p$?

Note: If my question seems obvious or previously asked, sorry for that. I am not sure what exact topic it is related to. I would be grateful if you could give me also some references.

Comment: This cannot be answered without some assumptions about why they reject to particiate or not!